# Can "infuse" be used without emotions or qualities?

Tags: meaning

According to dictionaries, "**to infuse A into B**" can only be used when A is an emotion or quality.

Below is a definition and example from Cambridge dictionary:

> **To infuse**: To fill someone or something with an **emotion** or **quality**

> The arrival of a group of friends on Saturday **infused new life into** the weekend.

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/infuse

Would it be possible to use infuse in a figurative way with things that are not emotions or qualities? Could you provide any examples? Thanks.

Comment: No, infused is wrong here. Bond yields go down with inflation but there is nothing automatically "part of the yield". **Bond yields can fluctuate based on inflation expectations**.

Answer (score 3):

I've never seen OP's cited usage before, but the intended meaning is obvious - it means inflation is ***factored in*** to bond yields (bond yields are adjusted to ***take account of*** inflation expectations).

The *literal* meaning of OP's ***infused*** doesn't look like a very good fit to me, but ***allowed for / adjusted for*** are perfectly natural alternatives for this context.

Comment: A bit like 'baked in'?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: I did think a bit about ***baked in*** while composing my answer (partly because I was having trouble calling to mind the idiomatic standard for the context, ***factored in***, and that one kept popping up like an [earworm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earworm)! :). But there might be a *semantic* difference too. I feel like ***baked in*** implies "arises naturally in the cited context", whereas this one has to be *explicitly* taken account of.

Comment: I have a feeling that 'baked in' can mean 'intentionally included as a fundamental ingredient', e.g. 'customer service is baked in to everything we do' (horrible, I know).

Comment: I think yesterday I was a bit thrown off because OP's ***infused*** was "a metaphor too far" for me, which somewhat soured *all* "recipe-based" figurative usages. Today, I realise your example is perfectly natural for earnest young entrepreneurs (if a bit "florid" for the likes of us! :) But I'm still not ready for *Customer Service is infused into everything we do*.

Comment: Oxford Languages seems to think it's OK, but like you, 'florid' is what I'd call it, and, yes, earnest. _1. fill; pervade. "her work is infused with an anger born of pain and oppression"  Similar: fill pervade permeate suffuse charge saturate imbue inspire inundate_

Comment: @deviza: ***the intended meaning is obvious***, as per my answer text. Stylistically, neither me nor Michael think much of it, but you're welcome to use it if you *do* like it (there should never be a problem with being understood). I must say I think it's a mistake to use *any* such "poetical expressions" in something described as a "report". But that's just "style advice" - you can take it or leave it.

Comment: Whatever - your continued follow-ups here have merely convinced me the question itself is Off Topic "writing advice" (a matter of opinion, with no one-and-only "correct" answer possible).

Comment: I tend to avoid flowery language in reports, but as @FumbleFingers says, it's style/writing advice.

Comment: I originally chose to interpret the question as asking something along the lines of *If my suggested phrasing **isn't** natural / common, what **is** the most common usage for the context?* A question to which in my mind there's one expression that's idiomatically head and shoulders above all others - ***factored in***. You need a good reason to use anything else.